# EmberJS: can't insert an element into the DOM that has already been inserted

Tags: javascript, dom, ember.js

**Edit:** stripped-down JSBin [link](http://www.emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/656/edit)

I'm running into a problem where when I create a new record, I get an error saying "uncaught exception: You can't insert an element into the DOM that has already been inserted".

An excerpt from `index.html`:

```
<ul id="flowList">
  {{#each}}
    {{#if isTemplate}}
      {{view App.FlowView}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>

<ul id='levelsList'>
  <ul id='level1'>
    {{#each}}
      {{#if isLevelOne}}
        {{view App.FlowView}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</ul>
```

I preloaded a Flow object with isLevelOne false, and isTemplate true.  It has a button which creates a new flow such that the computed property isLevelOne is true, and the property isTemplate is false -- I verified this in the Ember Inspector.  However, when this happens, I get the an `uncaught exception: You can't insert an element into the DOM that has already been inserted`, although the page seems to render alright.  When I try to refresh the page (with the new record saved into the store) it then fails to render the page and throws an `Error: Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.`  Neither of these errors make any sense to me -- any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: FlowView template included below**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='flow-view'>
  <li {{bind-attr id=title class=":flow isTemplate"}}>
    {{#if isTemplate}}
      <button {{action "insertIntoSandbox" this}}>&plus;</button>
    {{/if}}
    <label>{{title}}</label>
    {{#unless isDefault}}
      <button {{action "removeFlow" this}} {{bind-attr class="isTemplate"}}>&minus;</button>
    {{/unless}}
   </li>
</script>
```

**Edit: PortkeyController added below**

```
App.PortkeyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    /**
     * @elem is the flow associated with the button -- can use this to duplicate
     */
    insertIntoSandbox: function(elem) {
      var _store = this.store;

      var newFlowJSON = elem.toJSON();
      console.log(newFlowJSON); // isDefault=true, isTemplate=true, params=[] from element
      delete newFlowJSON.id; // might be unnecessary?

      newFlowJSON.title = 'gg';
      newFlowJSON.level = 1;
      newFlowJSON.isLevelOne = false;
      var newFlow = _store.createRecord('flow', newFlowJSON);
      newFlow.save();
  },
});
```

Comment: What's FlowView?  And is there a reason you are duping up on the uls?

Comment: FlowView is a View that's also hooked up to a template defined in another part of index.html.  The view doesn't really have much purpose now, but I created it so I can bind some jQuery actions to it later.  I'm duping up on the `ul`s because I plan on having more than one level, but for debugging I've gotten rid of the other ones.

Comment: Can you add the flow view's template, sorry, I should have been more specific ;)

Comment: Alright, updated the post.

Comment: I assume your controller is an array controller, do you have an item controller for each item?  or is it just iterating models

Comment: I'm just using an ArrayController, pretty sure its just iterating models.  The controller has one action (insertIntoSandbox) which basically creates a copy of another element (converting toJSON(), then making a few modifications and creating a record/saving).  It seems to be doing its job from looking at the Ember Inspector.

Something unrelated that I just found is that if I create a new flow with isLevelOne set to false, the page renders fine (although the element won't show up, obviously)

Comment: if you do `isTemplate` true, does it work fine?  if you get rid of the ul/lis, does it work fine?  let's all those guys and add them in one at a time until it starts breaking

Comment: Alright I think there must (somehow) be something wrong in the way I'm creating new records -- I tried completely commenting out the second `{{#each}}` statement and adding Flows to the first {{#each}} is throwing errors. I'll update the main post with some controller information.

Comment: K, so beside switching to the rest adapter, this jsbin seems to be working, http://jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/657/edit

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.  I noticed that the difference between the working and the broken jsbins was that I used `Ember.View.create()` instead of `Ember.View.extend`.  Could you perhaps quickly discuss maybe in an answer when you should be using which?  In the guides on the webpage they used create, which is why I used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspected as much, Ember usually goes haywire with invalid HTML when attempting to remove/add elements.  (I'm not sure if it's Ember, or the browser helping by injecting the closing tag for you, and then Ember not removing the browser helped tag)

The FlowView is missing the closing `LI` tag.

Comment: Crap sorry because of the commented out code I didn't copy-paste it in properly.  In index.html there actually is a closing `li` tag.  My bad.

Comment: no worry, will you update what it is, and I'll try and reproduce.